# ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource (Null PointerException)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

So i have found exactly what causes my problem but don't know how to remedy it. First of all i have a list that looks like this.
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r386x.png)

And i can fill this listview with 5 items or less and click on any of the items, and the alert dialog will pop up without any problems.
But when i try to add 6 or more items to the listview, AND Click on any of the items the program crashes. and gives me the error of

```
12-18 03:31:27.582: D/AndroidRuntime(2187): Shutting        down VM
12-18 03:31:27.582: W/dalvikvm(2187): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x95b57648)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$1.getView(AlertController.java:879)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2161)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1079)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-18 03:31:27.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And the code:

```
    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    public MyListAdapter(){
        super(UserOrderMenu.this,R.layout.itemview, customerItems);
    }

    @Override // position = is which listview item
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View itemView = convertView;

        if(itemView == null){ //makes sure we have a view to work with
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.itemview,parent,false);
        }

        //find the item to work with. using item class and customerItem ArrayList
        final Item currentItem = customerItems.get(position);
            //currentItem is the current Item object @ location position
            //customerItems is the ArrayList that is storing all the Item objects

        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonTrashCan);
        imageview.setClickable(true);
        imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                remove(currentItem); //this removes the current item fromt the ListView
                notifyDataSetChanged(); //this notifies the Arrayadapter to update

                float t1price, t2price, t3price, t4price, t5price;
                System.out.println(currentItem.getTopping1Used());

                if(currentItem.getTopping1Used()){      
                    t1price = currentItem.getTop1P();

                }else
                    t1price = 0;

                if(currentItem.getTopping2Used()){
                    t2price = currentItem.getTop2P();
                }else
                    t2price =0;

                if(currentItem.getTopping3Used()){
                    t3price = currentItem.getTop3P();
                }else
                    t3price = 0;

                if(currentItem.getTopping4Used()){
                    t4price = currentItem.getTop4P();
                }else
                    t4price =0;

                if(currentItem.getTopping5Used()){
                    t5price = currentItem.getTop5P();       
                }else
                    t5price =0;
                    findTotalPrice(-t1price,-t2price,-t3price,-t4price,-t5price,true);
                    findTotalPrice(-currentItem.getItemP());                
            }
        });

        //Item Name
        TextView n = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
        n.setText(currentItem.getItem());

        //Item Price
        //left here
        // do we want to add User Selected Toppings to the total price on the List View?
        //if so use currentItem.getTopping1Used();
            // then currentItem.getTop1P();
        TextView p = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemPrice);    
        p.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getItemP()));

        return itemView;
    }

}//end of MyListAdapter Class





private void populateListView(){ //this is how to add an item to ListView
    customerItems.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null)); //remove later
    customerItems.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null,""));
    ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter;

    try{
         adapter = new MyListAdapter();
         ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code would crash when there are only 5 `Item` in `customerItems`. Make sure you have more than 5 there.

Comment: Actually, it seems to crash whenever i add 6 or more items to the listview, Then proceed to click on any of the 6 or more items. The only way it works is if i only add 5 or less items.

Comment: Cancer can you explain more on why customerItems would crash with only 5 in there. I am a bit new (student) and any knowledge would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @hiRawr I think you should remove `remove(currentItem);` Why do you have it anyways?

Comment: when the trashcan button is pressed, that function removes that item from the listview(after calling notifydatasetchanged)

Comment: can you tell me exactly on what line it crashes?

Comment: I believe it is crashing at line 394; of this code https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java because that is what my log cat is telling me

Comment: from my understanding the method createviewfromresource should never be called because i override the getView Function which calls createviewfromresource. So why does my code fail at the createviewFromResource line?

Comment: interesting, can you paste the whole exception stack trace(other lines before createViewFromResource is called). Then we can see what calls `createviewfromresource`

Comment: ok i posted it, although the SO format is wrong will figure out how to fix

Comment: It seems your `MyListAdapter` is maybe not correctly set as adapter. Your `getView()` is not called. How do you create it and set as your array adapter?

Comment: i posted the way i create my listview. It is under populatelistview()

Comment: For some reason the problem seemed to be when i called the multiple choice alert dialog, after clicking the listview. So i ended up creating my own custom alertdialog and it is working now. Thank you for the help though!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the first 4 lines of your getView method with the following code. It should work.

```
    View itemView = convertView;

   if(itemView == null){ //makes sure we have a view to work with
       LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)yourContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemview, parent , false);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but i tried various forms of the above code to no avail. I still receive the null pointer exception if i had 6 or more items to the listview.